# Resizing picker in Titanium Studio (Iphone)

Tags: ios, resize, titanium-mobile, picker

I am new to mobile development with Titanium Studio. I want to create a picker with a little smaller size. I tried setting the Height and Width property but of no use. And I came across below link:

[Changing the height of the picker](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/6851/change-height-of-the-picker)

But I saw that it scales the whole picker including the content in it. I want to reduce the size of the picker without reducing the size of its content. And any idea to customize the picker like changing the background color would be more helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't do this. Apple may reject you for transforming native controls [See this post.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11928026/874257)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not try to modify the picker. If you do any transforming in the UI controls of Apple, you'll get a rejection from Apple, since this is a Apple Specific UI element, so any egregious resizing of it will violate the Human Interface guidelines. The general rule is to not use scaling transforms with any of the native UI elements, Apple is big on the unified look and feel so many reviewers will rip you for it.

Please refer the following links

[IOS Human interface guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH1-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

setting the height or width of the picker actually set the height or width of the rows/ entries of the picker. similarly it will effect the  width of the Colmms of the picker, if you are using the multi picker.

i will suggest that u use a model window and add background color/image then add the picker to thad window. you can apply animation on opening and closing of model window. you can also specify the position of the picker in this way.
hope this will help you to achieve what you are trying